# Rewriting EBP stack return value

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, stack, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

Hi I'm trying to write an overflow exploit for a simple program that I've built. Bellow is the C program that I've written.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *string_in = "Did not work";

int test(char *this){
char sum_buf[6];
strncpy(sum_buf,this,24);
return 0;
}

void hello(){
printf("hello man");
string_in = "If this triggered, it means our shell code is working\n";
return;
}

int main(int argc, void **argv){

test("01234567890123456789\x00\x40\x06\x02");
printf("My string is %s",string_in);
return 0;

}
```

Basically what happens is that the string is suppose to be read in an overwrite EBP with the value of 0x00400602, which is the return address of my function hello(). I know that this is the value of the address for my function hello since objdump -d test_stack.o. From the object dump, I can tell that rsp has been advanced 20 bytes as shown bellow

```
00000000004005b4 <test>:
  4005b4:   55                      push   %rbp
  4005b5:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4005b8:   48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
  4005bc:   48 89 7d e8             mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp)
  4005c0:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
  4005c7:   00 00 
  4005c9:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
  4005cd:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4005cf:   48 8b 4d e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rcx
  4005d3:   48 8d 45 f0             lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
  4005d7:   ba 18 00 00 00          mov    $0x18,%edx
  4005dc:   48 89 ce                mov    %rcx,%rsi
  4005df:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  4005e2:   e8 a9 fe ff ff          callq  400490 <strncpy@plt>
  4005e7:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4005ec:   48 8b 55 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
  4005f0:   64 48 33 14 25 28 00    xor    %fs:0x28,%rdx
  4005f7:   00 00 
  4005f9:   74 05                   je     400600 <test+0x4c>
  4005fb:   e8 a0 fe ff ff          callq  4004a0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
  400600:   c9                      leaveq 
  400601:   c3                      retq   

0000000000400602 <hello>:
  400602:   55                      push   %rbp
  400603:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400606:   b8 6d 07 40 00          mov    $0x40076d,%eax
  40060b:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  40060e:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400613:   e8 98 fe ff ff          callq  4004b0 <printf@plt>
  400618:   48 c7 05 0d 0a 20 00    movq   $0x400778,0x200a0d(%rip)        #
```

Since sub $20,%rsp I know that I need to write atleast 20 bytes ... but I'm not sure how much more I need to write to get to my rbp. Its possible that from my calq's, I need to write 8 or my bytes since there are 2 x calls. Though I'm really not sure how much I need to write.

I compile my program like so ...

```
gcc -g stack.c -o test_stack.o
execstack -s test_stack.o
```

Since I'm using ubuntu 11, my kernel version is like 3.0.17 so I know that my aslr is on by default. I may need to turn that off, but I don't know how to do that. Also I'm running a i386:x86_64. Can I tell what my stack actually looks like during a run? How can I get this to work and how do I find how much I need to write?

Thanks for the help

Comment: One problem I see is that you're not using enough bytes for the function's address. You need 32 bits: `\x00\x40\x06\x01`. In addition, I think you might need to reverse the order of those bytes because the x86 stores 0x00400601 in memory as 0x01, 0x06, 0x40, 0x00. Finally, I don't know if my suggestions will help. It kind of depends on the way gcc creates your stack frame. You're best off single-stepping in a debugger so that you can see what's happening.

Comment: Your right, I forgot to input the last byte. Thanks I'll see if this works.

Comment: Lol, now I'm not getting a stackoverflow error. Thats awesome! But for whatever reason its not printingf().

Comment: `sub    $0x20,%rsp` allocates 32 bytes for the stack frame, not 20 (hexadecimal notation).

Comment: I haven't done assembly in a while so i overlooked 0x as hex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the first problem was that I had to turn off stack protect with the -fno-stack-protector flag on. Once I did that it became much easier to overwrite my buffer. The second problem was that even if the string was read and stored with little endian, the opcode and operand seemed to be interpreted with big endian. I don't understand why this is the case. Lastly, it wasn't the EBP stack frame that I was interested in overwritting ... it was the return address of my function. This meant that instead of writing 24 bytes, I needed to effectively overwrite a whopping 32 bytes. I finally got the program to work!